# Live data calculation as user inputs data

Tags: jquery

I have this table with inputs in it for generating quotations and invoices for clients. The main goal is to calculate the results as the user inputs and changes prices and quantities.

I'm trying to do the same for the subtotal, taxes and grand total but just get NaN.

Rows can be added as the user needs via jQuery wich is also used to do de calculation with .live() (.on is not working for me)

Pleas check this jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/alexdoria/yJGMn/2/

This is the jQuery I'm using:

```
$("input.op").live('input', function() {
   $("tr.row").each(function() {
      var qt = parseFloat($(this).find("input.cant").val());
      var pr = parseFloat($(this).find("input.price").val());
      var subParcial = qt * pr;

      $(this).find("input.parc").val(subParcial.toFixed(2));

      //subLiveCalc = function(){
      var subs = 0;
      $("input.parc").each(function(){
         subs += parseFloat($(this).text());
      });
      $("div#partials span#subtotal").text(subs);
      //}
      //subLiveCalc();
   });  
});
```

Comment: to use `on()` as a replacement for `live()` change to this `$("#data").on('input', 'input.op', function () {`

Comment: Thank you @gillyspy, I made the change and worked perfectly.

Comment: Beauty. feel free to voteup the comments that help! :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that you aren't checking for blanks: `parseFloat` will return NaN if you call it on an empty string (which is what happens when any of the input fields are blank). You should put in a check for blank/invalid input fields: if any of the required fields are blank or parse to NaN then don't bother completing the calculation or updating the totals/subtotals.

Comment: That just did it! thanks. I insert a verification for the blank values and set them to 0 if was the case. Also changed some `.text()` into `.val()` please check the update at [link](http://jsfiddle.net/alexdoria/yJGMn/47/)